# M1 mac - Xcode 14.3 - Failed to render and update auto layout status

Tags: xcode, storyboard, apple-m1, swift-package-manager, ibdesignable

Upgraded to Xcode 14.3 and now all my storyboards won't render IBDesignable's throwing an error:

```
/Users/****/Documents/Projects/****/****/Modules/Onboarding/Base.lproj/Onboarding.storyboard 
Failed to render and update auto layout status for ****ViewController (3EC-3V-hGn): 
dlopen(****.app, 0x0001): tried: '/****' (no such file),
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot****.app' (no such file), 
'****.app' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

This all worked fine in 14.2 (well to a degree, Xcode 14 has been incredibly buggy and riddled with memory leaks). I found a suggestion on stackoverflow to set "Build Active Architecture Only" to "No" for debug builds, and add "macOS" to the "Supported Platforms" for debug. When I do this, I get a compile error popup, saying that my swift package (targeting iOS 15 + macos 11)

```
can't find the module for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64-apple-ios-simulator
```

Asking me if I want to turn on Rosetta and try again, or ensure that my package has all the required architectures. I can't find anything online about what i'm supposed to add to my package to fix this, or another workaround for the first issue, and i'd like to not enable Rosetta if possible

Any advice?

Comment: facing same issue with m1

Comment: @RameshSanghar i've opened a few tickets with the apple feedback assistant about this and another storyboard issue that keeps popping up a "report a bug" button along the top. If you haven't done so already, please create your own as well. The more people that open tickets, the more likely it will get fixed

Comment: ok I will, and temporarily I have fixed it with changing build active architectures only to false for debug in build settings.

Comment: @RameshSanghar this didn't work for me. When using SPM it complains that packages aren't using the correct architecture, but I can't find any settings to change or info about it online

Comment: keep trying you will find some solution.
also try running Xcode with rosseta it will run all architectures just like intel processor, just it will run slow

Comment: many packages are created for old architecture and so they create issues when running on M1

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin have you managed to find any solution and/or workaround to that? I encountered the exact same issue after updating to Xcode 14.3 and would appreciate any help on the topic.

Comment: @KBakalov I gave up and down graded to 14.2 (by downloading it again from the apple developer site). Please open a ticket on feedback assistant to let them know you have this issue too. It won't get fixed unless many people report it